# Some iPad web browsers do not render some MathJax codes

Tags: ios, ipad, web-browser, javascript, latex

As we know, well-known iPad web browsers such as Safari, Chrome, Firefox, ... support JavaScript, which is needed for rendering MathJax codes on many websites like Stack Exchange.

However, I have been informed that some parts of MathJax codes on some SE posts, like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3790253/656359), cannot be rendered on some web browsers such as Safari and Yandex while such codes can be rendered perfectly in the preview. It is worth noting that some other well-known web browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge do not have such a problem.

Now, my question is whether some changes in the settings of the web browsers should be effected to resolve the problem or this problem is related to some programming issues such as browser or SE bugs, which are beyond device users' control?